# redux saga wait for put to finish?

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I want to call 2 api calls sequentially.

Two apis are working fine separately.

I make a saga(?) which does

```
yield put(createAction1(arg1))
yield put(createAction2(arg2))
```

but I think they run concurrently (execution order is not guaranted)

I googled and found github issues which suggest to do

```
response1 = yield call(apiCallFunc, createAction1(arg1))
response2 = yield call(apiCallFunc, createAction2(arg2))
```

Then I'll have to `success` actions for response1 and response2.
I wonder if there's no way to reuse already created saga(?) using `put` ?

- edit

I don't know the proper name for `checkout` in the following example. I called them saga(?) in my question..
I'd like to utilize already existing `checkout` or `rootSaga` which handles `CHECKOUT_REQUEST` action..

Say I have `function* checkout1() function* checkout2, function* checkout3` inside `checkout1` i'd like to use `checkout2` and `checkout3`

```
function* checkout() {
  // query the state using the exported selector
  const cart = yield select(getCart)

  // ... call some API endpoint then dispatch a success/error action
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  while (true) {
    yield take('CHECKOUT_REQUEST')
    yield fork(checkout)
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "already created saga"? Could you explain your use case a bit more?

Comment: So your question is how to reuse this particular kind of saga: *on action X: API request X -> success/error*. Am I right? If so, it is possible to make a factory function that returns sagas like `rootSaga`, but with custom actions a custom API call.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you want to yield some generator function from another generator function.

Then in your function* checkout1 you can yield the other two generators

```
function* checkout1 {
  try {
    yield call(checkout2)
    yield call(checkout3)
    yield put(successAction())
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(errorAction())
  }
}
```

or you can do in two try-catch blocks

```
function* checkout1 {
  try {
    yield call(checkout2)
    yield put(successAction1())
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(errorAction1())
  }

  try {
    yield call(checkout3)
    yield put(successAction2())
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(errorAction2())
  }
}
```

or whatever other combination you need.